# Running akka within an SBT build task: reference configuration unexpectedly missing

Tags: sbt, akka

I'm trying to run a rather simple HTTP POST request within a task I wrote for my SBT build, and seeing that SBT does not seem to have helpers for that, I settled on spray-client to accomplish this task.

In a `project/dependencies.sbt` file I put the following:

```
resolvers += "spray.io repo" at "http://repo.spray.io/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.3",
  "io.spray" % "spray-client" % "1.2.0")
```

And my task is implemented by:

```
def uploadSite(version: String, siteArchive: File, log: Logger): HttpResponse = {

  def request: HttpRequest = Post(siteUploadUrl,
    MultipartFormData(Map(
    // abridged
    ))

  implicit val system = ActorSystem() // <-- Exception HERE!
  try {
    import system.dispatcher

    val future: Future[HttpResponse] = pipelining.sendReceive(request)

    Await.result(future, 1 minute)
  }
  finally system.shutdown()
}
```

The task fails when I run it with the following exception:

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:115)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:138)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:150)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:155)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:197)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:136)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:470)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:93)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:82)
    at MyIO$.uploadSite(MyIO.scala:65)
```

My basic analysis is that the `reference.conf` file that can be found in `akka-actor_2.10-2.2.3.jar` is not read, for some reason that escapes me and maybe has something to do with how SBT manages its classpath for running the build.

Some precisions: I'm on SBT 0.13.0 (hence Scala 2.10 for the build code) and I've checked that the aforementioned akka-actor jar indeed contains a reference.conf file which is as expected. When looking at what I *guess* might be related to the build execution classpath (`reload plugins` then `show runtime:fullClasspath` in sbt), that jar appears in the list.

I also failed at googling anything relevant, being unable to convey that the problem lies with running akka from *within an SBT build*.

In the end, I really have no idea how the 'akka' configuration key could be missing. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The really annoying thing about akka is that you need to update the thread local context classloader for the generic setting, and a lot of tools (like sbt) do not, because they do not know what thread you're running on or which classloader you will need.

Here's [an example from the activator](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/blob/master/project/LocalTemplateRepo.scala#L45-L50) build:

```
val cl = ??? // Some mechanism of getting Akka's classpath with your classes too
val old = Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader
Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(cl)
try doSomethingWithAkka()
finally Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(old)
```

---

Edit (by OP) so that this is more visible than in the comments:

Akka (since 2.0) chooses the class loader it uses in ActorSystem (when it's not passed as an argument) by picking the first available (and non-null) among:

1. `Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader`
2. `getClassLoader` on the class of a non-Akka stack frame up the call stack
3. `ActorSystem.getClass.getClassLoader`

So that's why the above solution of mutating the context class loader works.

As to the class loader to use in practice, I got the expected behaviour with `val cl = getClass.getClassLoader` (from my build definition class) since that class loader contains all the build definition, plugins and dependencies. Also it effectively makes step 1 above behave like step 2.

In the end though, I've settled with just creating the ActorSystem by calling `ActorSystem("someName", ConfigFactory.load(cl), cl)` and not touching the context class loader, which seems somewhat cleaner (and less frightening to someone like me who does not know what the context class loader is or does)

**TL;DR** Instead of

```
val system = ActorSystem()
```

write

```
val cl = getClass.getClassLoader
val system = ActorSystem("mySystem", ConfigFactory.load(cl), cl)
```

Comment: If the context class loader is not fit for the purpose, then why is it set? Also, you can just pass the cl into the ActorSystem once at creation and that should be enough.

Comment: It's more about *what* CCL to set, as opposed to if it's fit for this purpose.  Given sbt is a multi-classloader environment, it makes no claim to set the CCL appropriately for you.  You must do so appropriately for Akka.

If you're loading/running Akka reflectively, then passing it in at creation can be tougher

Comment: I disagree: the CCL is to be set IFF there is a specific class loader which code running on that thread should preferably use. If there is no such CL, then CCL should be null, and in that case Akka would probably even do the right thing by itself (using the CL which has loaded the ActorSystem class).

Comment: So you're saying sbt should set the CCL to null during its execution of tasks?  I think that breaks anything using ObjectInputStream from working correctly as well.

Comment: From a user’s perspective (for example the OP here) I would expect the CCL set during task execution to have visibility of all dependencies of the build definition, but that does not seem to be the case. Maybe this is the bug?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've only just been able to test this idea and it worked all right with `val cl = getClass.getClassLoader`, or alternatively creating the ActorSystem with that ClassLoader instead of setting the CCL.

Comment: That said, even though the technical details are somewhat beyond me, I must agree with @RolandKuhn that it seems weird that the context class loader would not contain the build definitions and dependencies (it seems to contain the sbt boot classpath)

Comment: @RolandKuhn for the user's OP, they actually need the classloader to be that of what is used to compile the project, not that used to define the task.

Also, the CL used to define a given task could span multiple classloaders successfully.  There is no good default for sbt, or else we'd have one.

Comment: Ah, I may have misunderstood the original question.  Yeah, in your OP you're using the classloader for the ActorSystem.  Again, given how sbt loads classes, it's hard for us to pick the "right" default, so right now we don't touch the CCL beyond setting it to the one used to *load sbt*.  This does not include plugins currently, but does allow all the forking serialization to work with Object{Output|Input}Stream.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer and comments. I took the liberty of editing the answer by adding the interesting bits from the comments and a concise solution so that it is more visible, should anyone encounter the same issue. Hope I didn't write anything wrong!

Comment: Yes, looks good to me, I just updated the Akka version since which this applies. Thanks!